# CSS zoomIn animation div position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a zoomIn animation box using animate.css . But i have a problem with the div position. While the animation takes place, the div moves from the right to the middle as the position. But while zoomIn animation is taking place, the divs should grow in the part where they are.

I have prepared a demo to make it clearer. What is missing here?

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/OayoxX)**

```css
.radar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.radar:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
 transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.radar:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.radar:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
 width:600px;
 height:600px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
 transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.35s ease 0.35s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.35s easet 0.35s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.radar:nth-child(5) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
 width:700px;
 height:700px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.4s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.4s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="radar"></div>
<div class="radar"></div>
<div class="radar"></div>
<div class="radar"></div>
<div class="radar"></div>
```

Comment: you didn't mention zoomIn in your code... does the following help... @keyframes zoomIn {
    from {top: 50%;}
    to {top: 50%;}
}

Comment: @AIqbal my zoomIn animation is : `@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3); 
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1; 
  }
}
.zoomIn {
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}`

Comment: removing the scale3d helps: ...
@keyframes zoomIn { 
  0% { top: 50%; opacity: 0;  } 
  50% { top: 50%; opacity: 0.5; } 
  100% { top: 50%; opacity: 1; } 
} 
.zoomIn { animation-name: zoomIn; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation that you are using looks like that:

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**So the transform property from the animation is overriding your transform property.**
Instead of transform: translate(-50%, -50%); you should use negative margins to center your elements.
Your first circle should look like that:

```
    .radar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-top: -150px; // add this
    margin-left: -150px; // add this
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #47b27f;
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(0, 162, 213, 0) 52%, rgb(83, 165, 125) 100%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    animation: zoomIn 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```